# unable to upload file to mysql using struts1

Tags: mysql, struts1

I am trying to upload a file into mysql database using struts1.But unable to doso,I am getting the error:FileNotFoundException.Here is my code...

1.**JSP Page:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>

<html:html>
<body>
<html:form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select a File :<html:file property="file"/>
<html:submit/>
</html:form>
</body>
</html:html>
```

2.**My Action Form**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.*;
import org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile;

public class UploadForm extends ActionForm{
private FormFile file;

public FormFile getFile(){
return this.file;
}

public void setFile(FormFile file){
this.file=file;
}
}
```

3.**Action Class**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.struts.action.*;
import org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile;

public class UploadAction extends Action{
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm                                form,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
UploadForm file=(UploadForm)form;
System.out.print("Executed");
FormFile formFile=file.getFile();
System.out.print("Executed1");
String fileName=formFile.getFileName();
System.out.print(fileName);
File file1=new File(formFile.getFileName());
System.out.print(">>>>");
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(file1);
System.out.print("*****");
Integer fileSize=formFile.getFileSize();
int insert=0;
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
Connection      con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
System.out.println("Connection Opened.");
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into upload values(?)");
pst.setBinaryStream(1,fin,fileSize);
insert=pst.executeUpdate();
System.out.print("File Uploaded.");
}
catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
if(insert!=0){
return mapping.findForward("success");
}
else{
return mapping.findForward("error");
}
}
}
```

I am getting error at this line in my Action Class:**FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(file1);**

Please help me to resolve this problem.